# Python: specify list type at creation without usage of np.float_()

Tags: python, list, types, empty-list

I am working with many lists in which float values will be stored.
Is there a simple way to specify the type of a list when creating it?
Since I continuously add values to the list in a loop, I would like to avoid the application of `np.float_()`. Can I specify that all variables that are added are automatically converted to the float type?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists in standard out-of-the-box Python are not limited to a particular data type, so it is not foreseen to define one when creating the list. Numpy arrays, on the other hand, have that limitation, so I think your best bet would be to create one via `np.array()` and specify the data type `float` with the `dtype` parameter, e.g.:

```
arr = np.array([7, 8, 9], dtype=float)
```